# Expresso Store: Search by SKU in control panel

Tags: expresso-store

My client would like to be able to search products by entering it's SKU, however this doesn't seem to be supported in the search in `Content > Edit` or `Store > Inventory`. Is there any way to search for a SKU in the control panel? If not how would I go about adding this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add this functionality with [Zenbu](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/zenbu), this module extends the Content > Edit display so you can add the columns you wish for the channels you wish, and ultimately sort and filter on them too.

Used it before, will do the job and you'll get your 30 day money back guarantee if its not quite right for you.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like it doesn't natively support Store but I can make an EE field with the SKU in.